# Docker Load Balancing Multiple Hosts Sessions Shared Memory

Tags: docker, cloud, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I don't know exactly how load balancing and app sessions work together. Hope someone can throw some light on this.

Lets say I have two nodes (host1, host2) and I am running on each of them my Web App. My Web App is using Sessions and the sessions are stored in memory.
Lets say we have a User called "Joe" and lets say the load balance will send Joe to "host1".

1. Will Joe always be served from "host1"?
2. If not, how does host2 know about his sessions, since they are different machines they don't share memory? Or do I need then to have a persistant DB for storing the session?
3. If yes, what happens if "host1" fails for some reasons? I guess then we are back to point 2.

I was going through the docker tutorials and references, I successfully spinned some virtual machines and multiple replicas, but I couldn't find anything that explained me these basics.

Thanks!